# user info is not loading in vue component after login

Tags: vue.js

I am using localstorage to save user info after a successful login. Then I want to put a v-if condition to filter whether the user is logged in or not. But the problem is, the localStorage returning null while I am trying to parse it in components. I am sharing the codes from component here :

```
data() {
    return {
        currentUser : {}
    }
},

mounted() {
    this.currentUser = localStorage.getItem('userInfo')
}
```

From the Template :

```
<span v-if="currentUser" class="dropdown-item dropdown-header text-right">{{ currentUser.name 
}}</span>
```

From console :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve that by just considering below two points **:**

- While storing the data in `localStorage`, store it as a string. In the below demo I will use `JSON.stringify()` to convert the `userInfo` object into a string.
- While fetching the data from `localStorage`, parse it using `JSON.parse()`

Working Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    userInfo: null
  },
    mounted() {
    this.getUserInfo();
  },
  methods: {
    saveUserInfo() {
        const userInfo = {
        id: 1,
        name: 'alpha'
      }
      localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(userInfo))
    },
    getUserInfo() {
        this.userInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'));
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p> <strong>UserName :</strong> {{ userInfo?.name }} </p>
  
  <button type="submit" @click="saveUserInfo">
   Save User Info
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

localStorage store as key-value pair; and the value is a type of string, you should parse it to a `JSONObject`

Comment: would you please tell me how to do that, thanks